# Typescript: object assignment with excess keys seems broken

Tags: javascript, typescript

First variant: I pass object data from the const. Second variant: I pass data directly in the function. Why do I have an error only in the second variant?

First:

```
const a = {
  name: '123',
  age: 30,
  excess: []
}

interface A {
  name: string
  age: number
}

const func = (e: A) => {
  console.log(e)
}

func(a) // no error
```

Second:

```
interface A {
  name: string
  age: number
}

const func = (e: A) => {
  console.log(e)
}

func({
  name: '123',
  age: 30,
  excess: [] // error
})
```

Comment: While I agree that there might be a consistency problem here, why would you ever give unneeded properties to an object literal used directly as a parameter?

Comment: [Excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) are only active when you *directly* pass an object. Not if you first assign the object to a variable and then use that variable. This is a documented feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript is fine with having extra properties as long as you provide a type with its’ required properties, But when you try to assign the object literal **directly** the `Excess property checks` is active and you get the error (`Type '{ x }' is not assignable to type 'Y'`).

Based on [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/typescript-excess-property-checks-6ffe5584f450):

> When TypeScript encounters object literal in assignments or when
> passed as an argument to functions it triggers an action called excess
> property checking.

So it checks whether the object has the exact properties or not.